# What's the RewriteRule in htaccess to redirect to a different port?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I want to redirect all the request like `url/api/something` to a different port (say 8000) with the same base URL

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/\w*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ?
```

What is the RewriteRule?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://123.45.67.891:3000/$1 [L,R=302]
```

If you want a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^2000$
```